# Segmentation fault in JVM for stack overflow, but only on VMWare

Tags: java, jboss, jvm, vmware

We have an app running on JBoss. This app has one or two bugs that cause it to infinity recurse, causing a stackOverflowException. not optimal, but not a disaster.

We've recently tried to move to VMWare, and the same exceptions have now become segmentation faults that bring down the entire application server and JVM with them.

not any stackOverflowException does this, and thus far I have been unable to create a simple piece of code that reproduces this bug.

Any ideas why this difference might exist?

Comment: Why not wait until the seg fault happens and then take a core dump? Seems to me the simplest way to find out what's going wrong.

Comment: tried that. core dump is too corrupted for gdb to even give me a useful backtrace. something went really wrong.

Comment: What OS (VM and physical)?  How much memory on the physical setup and in the VM?  Same number of CPUs in the physical setup and virtual setup?  (And how many?)

Comment: it happens on both debian and on redhat, with 4G to 8G or ram, and the host OS, on ESX and ESXi, with oracle hotspot jvm, java versions 1.6 u 12 and u27.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There could be a difference in the way memory is handled. Ie you have a different OS version, or there is a bug in the interaction with the VMWare.

You are right that this shouldn't be possible.  I would also check you have current, supported version of Java.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a bug with Oracle/Sun JVM HotSpot running on a Linux System.

If you try the app using a Oracle/Sun JVM you will get a Segmentation fault error. On the other hand if you try to run this same app using the OpenJDK you'll probably see a StackOverflow error.

Answer (score 0):

If the JVM is segfaulting *and* your application doesn't involve an native code libraries (called using JNI or JNA), this is evidence of a platform bug of some kind.

In this case, it is hard to know for sure if the real fault is in the JVM or in VMWare.  I'd be inclined to blame VMWare for not providing a faithful implementation of the behaviour of an "ordinary" PC.  However, it is possible that the JVM is unwarranted making assumptions about the way an x86 or x86-64 processor will behave when a Java stack overflows and the processor attempts to read or write the stack's guard page.